# Find the area of polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

The questions is to find the area in the bounded region in polar coordinates

$r = \sqrt{\theta}$ from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$

Here is what I did:
I got the integral of $\cfrac{1}{2}\theta d\theta$ from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$.
Then I integrated and got $\cfrac {1}{4} \theta ^2$ from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$.
As a result, I got $\cfrac {7}{16}\pi^2$

But I felt that there might be something wrong with my answer. Can someone tell me about this? Thanks

Comment: to find the area of the region in polar coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area is $\cfrac12\displaystyle\int_{{3\pi}/2}^{2\pi} [r(\theta)]^2 d\theta = \cfrac12\displaystyle\int_{{3\pi}/2}^{2\pi} \theta d\theta$ and this should return $\cfrac{7}{8}\pi^2$. Check your work again.